# How to get a list of all elements in a table with the same sequence number?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, lambda

I would like to get a list of all elements in a table with the same sequence number, but I don't know the sequence number. It must be the last sequence number in the table for the selected line.

```
SequenceNo LineId SubId DataCol1 DataCol2 DataCol3
33         1      1     35       36       37
33         1      2     25       26       27
33         1      3     45       46       47
34         1      1     23       42       32
34         1      2     42       11       12
34         1      3     23       33       32
```

So my code so far is:

```
Context.NextLineSequeceData.Where(c => c.LineId == LineId).OrderByDescending(c=>c.SequenceNo).ToList();
```

How can I modify it so I only get data with the SequenceNo 34?

Comment: Do you need the code that handles it on C# or on SQL server level?

Comment: I would love to see the lambda expression, but SQL would be good as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Linq, I prefer simple and readable statements, so here is a simple solution:

```
var maxSequence = Context.NextLineSequeceData
                  .Where(x => x.LineId == selectedLineId)
                  .Select(x => x.SequenceNo)
                  .Max();

var result = Context.NextLineSequeceData.Where(x => x.SequenceNo == maxSequence);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the last row of the sample above - this is an example how to achieve this on SQL server:

```
declare @t table(i int, ch char(5))
insert into @t 
select 1 ,'aa'
union all select 5 ,'bb'
union all select 6 ,'vv'
union all select 2,'sd'
union all select 2,'sf'
union all select 1,'sdf'
union all select 5,'sf'
select * from @t

;with cte as (
select rn=row_number() over(order by i),i,ch
from @t)
select *
from cte

;with cte as (
select rn=row_number() over(order by i),i,ch
from @t)
select * 
from cte c
where c.rn=(select max(rn) from cte)
```